# xively (replacement for Cosm (replacement for Pachube)) examples and charts

Tags: cosm, xively

Does the new Xively have curl examples of the various read and write functions specifically for the new API?  If so, where?  If not, can we have some?

Also, are the embedable charts gone?  If not, where are they?

Answer (score 2):

The API has not changed at all so all of your existing calls should work as before.

You can [read the documentation here](https://xively.com/dev/docs/api/).